# What is the difference between Runnable and Future in Scala?

Tags: multithreading, scala

Coming from Java background, I recently started coding on Scala as my job required.

I have read through [the concurrency guide for Scala](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/concurrency.html) and know how to use future to perform asynchronous task.

I'm wondering:

1. If the asynchronous task I want to perform doesn't have a return value, are there any difference between using a runnable that submitted to a thread and using a future alone?
2. What is the performance of future compared with runnable? Or am I comparing apple with orange?

Comment: Apple with orange, yes. The two things are not at all interchangeable.

Comment: @Duncan That's exactly what happened to me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Future` (`scala.concurrent.Future`, not to be confused with the one in Scalaz) is implemented using `Runnable` underneath - see `PromiseCompletingRunnable`. In many ways it's just a wrapper that offers nice high-level functionality (in particular, composition using `flatMap`). So the behaviour and performance are very similar - a `Future` will be *very slightly* less performant than a "raw" `Runnable` because it involves instantiating a couple more wrapper classes, but this is unlikely to be noticeable in practice if the future is doing any actual work (and especially if running it involves creating a new thread). If you create a `Future[Unit]` and throw it away, this is indeed much the same as creating a `Runnable` and submitting it to the same `ExecutionContext`.

Comment: I am expecting future is similar to runnable somehow. Are there any reference state that future uses runnable underneath? In addition, how is a future with returning values achieved if it is a wrapped runnable?

Comment: I don't have any reference, just looking at the standard library source. Values are returned via a `Promise`; when you create a `Future` the actual implementation is 1. Create a `Promise` 2. Make a `PromiseCompletingRunnable` that performs the computation you gave it, and then completes the `Promise` with it 3. Submit the `PromiseCompletingRunnable` to the `ExecutionContext` 4. Return the `Promise`.

Answer (score 1):

A Future is 'a container' for something which runs async (it's a monad).

So, you get a toolbox to handle the computation result / failures.

Have you read this: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html ?